# Invalid SOAP message due to XML Schema validation failure. > The element 'Credentials' in namespace

Tags: python, xml, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to use stamps.com WSDL service - here is the link: http://34.212.2.126:8000/api/TEST/

I'm getting this message:

> Server raised fault: 'Invalid SOAP message due to XML Schema validation failure. 
>   The element 'Credentials' in namespace 'http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2017/04/swsim/swsimv62' has incomplete content.
>   List of possible elements expected: 'IntegrationID' in namespace 'http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2017/04/swsim/swsimv62'.'

This is the python code I'm using:

```
    client = Client(stamp_endPoint)
    client.set_options(port='SwsimV62Soap')

    response = client.service.AuthenticateUser()
    return HttpResponse(response)`
```

Here is the WSDL file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Q9btduOt7AeVQtQk1mSkZ3RkU/view

I have login Credentials (IntegrationID,Username,Password)  but i don't know how to insert them.